# KendoUI Listview HeaderTemplate

Tags: listview, kendo-ui, checkboxlist

I have the following code and I cannot get the HeaderTemplate to work. I need the option to select all checkbox at once or deselect them "options" in the header. Here is my code:

**Jsfiddle Example would be great.**

```
    <div class="row container-fluid">
        <div class="span3" style="background-color: #F2F2F2;">
            Select Row Profile:<br>

            <div class="space5"></div><select style="width: 100%">
                <option value="1">
                    one
                </option>

                <option value="2">
                    two
                </option>

                <option value="3">
                    three
                </option>

                <option value="4">
                    four
                </option>
            </select>

            <div class="k-listview" id="listView_row" style="width:100%; height: 124px; overflow-y:scroll;"></div><script id="myTemplate_row" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">

            <div class="item click" data="${age}">
                <input type="checkbox" class="click" />
                <span class="checkbox">#:age#</span>
            </div>
            </script>
        </div>

        <div class="span3" style="background-color: #F2F2F2;">
            Select Column Profile:<br>

            <div class="space5"></div><select style="width: 100%">
                <option value="1">
                    one
                </option>

                <option value="2">
                    two
                </option>

                <option value="3">
                    three
                </option>

                <option value="4">
                    four
                </option>
            </select>

            <div class="k-listview" id="listView_col" style="width:100%; height: 124px; overflow-y:scroll;"></div><script id="myTemplate_col" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">

            <div class="item click" data="${age}">
                <input type="checkbox" class="click" />
                <span class="checkbox">#:age#</span>
            </div>
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="float: right;">
        <button>Apply</button>
    </div><script>
       $(document).ready(function () {


         var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                      transport: {
                          read: {
                             url: "json/_crosstab_sub_data.json", dataType: "json"

                          }
                     }
                    });
              $("#listView_row").kendoListView({
                    dataSource: dataSource,
                    template: kendo.template($("#myTemplate_row").html()),
                    headertemplate:"<div class='item click' id='headerTemp' data='*'><input type='checkbox' class='click' /><span class='checkbox'>All<\/span><\/div>"

                });

              $("#listView_col").kendoListView({
                    dataSource: dataSource,
                    template: kendo.template($("#myTemplate_col").html()),
                    headertemplate:"<div class='item click' id='headerTemp' data='*'><input type='checkbox' class='click' /><span class='checkbox'>All<\/span><\/div>"
                });


            });

    </script>
```

Comment: I think it will be 'headerTemplate' and not 'headertemplate'. I have used it in this way and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

The ListView does not support such headertemplate configuration as the one that you shared (I guess you were watching the Grid which has headetTemplate for the different columns).

All the options that are available are covered [here](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/listview).

Nevertheless you can just add a simple div before that **#listView_row** element and it will act as a header.